# Jenkins and Sonar, how to pass down parameter from Jenkins to Ant to create several Sonar projects

Tags: ant, jenkins, sonarqube

I am using Jenkins+Sonar+Ant+java. I am now triggering a Sonar analysis from Jenkins during the night. However, because our full analysis takes so long I would like to define a Jenkins job that analyses only past 1 days of code using the Cutoff plugin (so in every commit, Sonar would analyse the committed code + one day of new code. Actually I would like to analyse only the newly committed code, maybe Cutoff should be 0 then?). For this to work I think I need to setup two different Sonar project names. On Sonar server, I would then have projects "Full analysis" and "New code analysis". The question is, how to define th ename in Jenkins? I think somehow, the Ant task that starts Sonar analysis needs to take the project name from Jenkins, but how is this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the properties sonar.projectKey and sonar.projectName on the ant command line, rather than in a properties file.  In Jenkins, you can do this in the Advanced parameters of an Ant builder.

Answer (score 1):

sonar ant task take project name from properties, you can specify `sonar.projectKey` and `sonar.projectName` for different analysis. [details](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+Sonar+Ant+Task)

Comment: yes exactly, but how can I define it in Jenkins? Since Jenkins is the one triggering the Sonar analysis, it needs to be the one defining the project name. Otherwise I need to define several different Ant targets...